# Commanding a Telegram Bot to trigger a PHP script via curl

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I would like to create a very simple thing: on my command of /call_the_website I want my Telegram Bot to curl a PHP script at https://www.google.com/call_the_website_script.php.

Is there an ready-made way? Or do I have to define my own command from scratch?

Comment: when you say curl a php script. Do you mean get the result from a php script using javascript?

Comment: Certainly you have write your own command. You need the get the "updates", check the "message text" and compare for the command string. Then you can do what you need and send a reply to the user.

Comment: @Ggg - I simply mean sending a GET or POST request.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - I don't even care much about sending a reply to the user. All I need is the bot to see the command, and trigger the PHP script living on a server somewhere.

Comment: Did you check https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook it seems like they already support webhook (way to go, imo)